# Android Room and Kotlin Boolean Array

Tags: android, arrays, kotlin, android-room

I’ve reviewed a lot of Stack answers related to this and I’m still not getting it.  I have an @Embedded class, but I’d rather this be a Boolean array with three elements.  Would someone please hit me with a clue stick and help me redesign this entity to handle this or provide the TypeConverter I need?  I’d rather not use a JSON/GSON converter if I can avoid it.

```
data class Bools (val a: Boolean = true,
                  val b: Boolean = true,
                  val c: Boolean = false)

@Entity(tableName = "people_table")
data class Person (@ColumnInfo(name = "first_name") val firstName: String,
                   @ColumnInfo(name = "last_name") val lastName: String,
                   @Embedded
                   val bool: Bools
){
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Int = 0
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: "I’d rather this be a Boolean array with three elements" -- ignore the Kotlin for the moment. What do you want the representation to be in your database schema? If the answer is "I want three columns", then what you have is your best answer, other than simply having the three `Boolean` properties directly in `Person`. If the answer is "I want a single column", then a `@TypeConverter` could handle it.

Comment: I think it makes the most sense, from a data storage standpoint, to have three separate columns.  From a code standpoint, it would be ideal if this were an array so that I could more quickly iterate through it or access the “elements” using integers.  Where I’m lost is how to bridge the gap from the DB storage to an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, I do not recommend that Room entities, Retrofit responses, and similar things be considered your in-memory data model. They are data transfer objects, as they are subject to limitations that your UI and in-app logic should not need to deal with. In the case of something like Retrofit, the way the data is organized and delivered by the server may bear little resemblance to how you want to work with the data in the app. In your case, it's that you want three distinct columns, which means three distinct Kotlin properties, whether in the entity or in an `@Embedded` object, as you have it.

A typical approach is to have a `PersonDTO` or `PersonEntity` or something be what Room uses, which you convert to/from `Person` objects that have your desired structure:

```
data class Person (val firstName: String,
                   val lastName: String,
                   val boolsheet: BooleanArray)

@Entity(tableName = "people_table")
data class PersonEntity (@ColumnInfo(name = "first_name") val firstName: String,
                         @ColumnInfo(name = "last_name") val lastName: String,
                         val a: Boolean = true,
                         val b: Boolean = true,
                         val c: Boolean = false
){
    constructor(somebody: Person): this(
      somebody.firstName,
      somebody.lastName,
      somebody.boolsheet[0],
      somebody.boolsheet[1],
      somebody.boolsheet[2]
    )

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Int = 0

    fun toPerson(): Person = Person(firstName, lastName, booleanArrayOf(a, b, c))
}
```

Now, `Person` and everything that deals with it knows nothing about Room, and you have the API that you want. `PersonEntity` would be used by your repository, hiding the details. And, if someday you need to have the repository also talk to a server, the repository can normalize between `Person` and the representation that you need for your Web service API.

If you don't like that, stick with your `Person` and `@Embedded`, and add a `val boolsheet = booleanArrayOf(bools.a, bools.b, bools.c)` to it, to get your `Boolean` values in a iterable structure.